# Remove the hash key while page redirection in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I need to remove the # hash key from the url.And I used these code?Is there any thing to add?Please find me a solution?

```
mySchoolApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
    templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
    title: 'Login Page',
    controller: "mainController"
  })
    .when("/login", {
    templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
    title: 'Login Page',
    controller: "mainController"
  })
    .when("/forgot", {
    templateUrl: "templates/forgot.html",
    title: 'Forgot Page',
    controller: "mainController"
  })
    .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/404'
  });
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Comment: While added the LocationProvider I am getting the error-
[$location:nobase] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$location/nobase

Comment: Click on that link.... it explains issue and solution to you!!

Answer (score 0):

You need add a base tag on your html header like this:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: Sometimes it may occur